# SceneKit : SCNPhysicsBody get current velocity

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, physics, scenekit

How can I get the current velocity of a SCNPhyisicsBody?

The velocity property does always return (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), and the physicsBody of the prensetationNode of my SCNNode is also nil.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Also how do you set the velocity directly on a SCNNode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the "current" velocity with

```
physicsBody.velocity
```

But this is valid only within the "game loop" callbacks (updateAtTime, didApplyAnimations, didSimulatePhysics, will/didRenderScene).

Comment: How did you become aware of this? Can't see this blatantly mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Does this mean you can only set `velocity` within game loop callbacks as well? Setting velocity so far doesn't seem to work, but will try the game loop callbacks. @Confused

Comment: I will have to build a project and check. Haven't tinkered with SceneKit physics for a long while. @Crashalot

Comment: @Confused ... just tried it, and setting the velocity property directly seems to have no effect (even within game loop functions).

Comment: @Confused were you able to set the velocity property directly to move SCNNodes? thanks for your help!

Comment: The answer is wrong. .velocity works **at any time**.  it "reports" the velocity as last calculated in the game loop.  As with @Crashalot I am finding it hard to set the velocity.

Answer (score 1):

...in your view controller, you have to use SCNSceneRendererDelegate protocol like

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController,SCNSceneRendererDelegate{...
```

and in the viewDidLoad method set the SCNView delegate to
    scnView.delegate=self

Then you can implement for example

```
func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: NSTimeInterval) {

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    let scene = scnView.scene
    let compass = scene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ObjectName", recursively: true)

    print((compass?.physicsBody?.angularVelocity)!)
}
```

this works in my case.
hope it helps a bit!