# SceneKit: move SCNNode by setting velocity property directly like in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnnode, scnscene

In SpriteKit, it's possible to move nodes by directly setting their `velocity` property.

This doesn't seem to work in SceneKit, however. Setting `velocity` -- both in game loop callbacks and outside of game loop functions -- seems to have no effect.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214609/scenekit-scnphysicsbody-get-current-velocity/31217353#31217353) from one of the Apple SceneKit engineers suggests accessing the velocity property is only possible during a game loop callback like `updateAtTime`.

So clearly there are limitations around the `velocity` property.

Is controlling the property directly not possible with SCNNodes?

Comment: Just now, first time, I've seen that this value is settable. https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514757-velocity Give me a few weeks to figure out how to setup a demoscene to test this, and I'll have a play with this. Without a programmer sitting next to me, I'm the world's slowest coder.

Comment: @Confused great find! reading through the notes it seems like it should work. will try again and report back. thanks!

Comment: @Confused found the answer, thanks for your help!

Comment: Well done! I didn't have a easy way to test it. Sorry. otherwise I would have done it. I am busy designing and writing at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Confused kindly pointed out, the docs show it is possible to set `velocity` directly: https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514757-velocity

The key is to use a dynamic body type, not a kinematic one (and obviously not a static one).